# Scrollable menu in a web page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have to create a menu whihc keeps moving based on the click on Next and previous buttons. What is the best method to achieve this.
 a sample will help me alot.

Comment: Not so easy to know what it is you want to do. Do some googling and find a menu example that does what you want and add a link to the example to your question. Then we may be able to tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at ASP.NET builtin wizard control.

> [Walkthrough ASP.NET Wizard Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/01/21/walkthrough-wizard-control-in-asp-net.aspx)
>
> [Wizard Control:Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15804/ASP-NET-2-0-Wizard-Control)

**Edit**
[Custom Paging in ASP.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx)

Comment: My menu is dynamic. like menu 1 to menu 25. I will show them 10 first and then when click on next i will show them the next 25

Comment: What kind of menu is it? A dropdown menu or ASP.NET menu or gridview rows ?

Comment: I think what you are after regardless of the underlying control (menu/gridview/repeater) is the No. of records fetched from the database. You will need to specify the startRowIndex & MaximumRows using SQL row_number() & between clause. Check out my updated reply for a link on the same.